# node.js write to file problems

Tags: node.js

hey guys so I'm having problems with trying to get my readme file to generate. Every time I put node index.js in to the terminal it says the fs.writetofile is not a function. but it still lets me put in the information of the readme.

this is the index.js file

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const fs = require('fs');
const generateMarkdown = require('./utils/generateMarkdown');
const path = require('path');

// TODO: Create an array of questions for user input
//this is the array of questions to put in the readme

function init(){

    inquirer.prompt([

        { 
          type: "input",
          message: "What is the title",
          name: "title",  
             },

        { 
          type: "input",
          message: "give a description",
          name: "description",  
             },

        {
           type: "input",
           message: "how do you install it",
           name: "installation",
        },
        
        {
            type: "input",
            message: "How do use it",
            name: "usage",
        },
          
        {
            type: "input",
            message: "github username",
            name: "name"
        },
        
      ]).then((data) => {
        const filename = `${data.title}.md`;

        fs.writeToFile(filename, generateMarkdown(data)), (err) =>{
          if (err){ 
              return console.log(err);
          }
          console.log('you have created a readme file.')
        }

      }
      );
    };

    
      
    //initialize app

    init();
```

```
//this is the generatmarkdownfile
    const InputPrompt = require("inquirer/lib/prompts/input");

//function for readme 
function generateMarkdown(data) {
  return `
  # ${InputPrompt.title}
    
  ## Description
      
  ${InputPrompt.description}
    
    
  ## Installation
    
  ${InputPrompt.installation}
    
  ## Usage
    
  ${InputPrompt.usage}
    
  ## Name
     
  ${InputPrompt.name}
  `;
  }
   

module.exports = generateMarkdown;
```

Answer (score 1):

Method name to write to file is not called `writeToFile` but it's called `writeFile` actually.

So replace `fs.writeToFile` with `fs.writeFile`.

**Edit:** The code below fixes the syntax issue you have with that extra parenthesis. Check what I have written in the comments.

```
fs.writeFile(filename, generateMarkdown(data), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('you have created a readme file.')
});
```

Comment: thank you! now it's giving me a invalid callback on line 46, I've tried moving it out of the .then function but it made it stopped the questions from prompting, do i have to call it when i am calling init(); ? thanks for the help

Comment: or do i have to declare a path?

Comment: The callback is not being passed inside the writeFile function because of an extra parenthesis you have in your code right after generateMarkdown(data).

Comment: i never would have saw that thank you !